# How to increase font size of Redgate SQL Data Compare tool

Tags: sql-server, redgate

How to increase the font size of entries displayed after comparing two databases? The size is extremely small.

I have tried every option displayed on the screen but no luck, none of the shortcuts for increasing font size work, and not much information is available on internet either.

Comment: You should ask **Red-Gate Support** for this - they (if anyone) will know!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust this via the "Make text, apps, and other items larger or smaller" option as described here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-text-apps-bigger-windows-10